# What is ratio of total number of people who read B newspaper

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a survey conducted with $95$ people on readership of two newspapers $A$ and $B$ , it was noted that $30$ people read both ,$20$ people read only $A$, $5$ Read only $B$ and balance $40$ read neither. What is ratio of people who read A to the total number of people who read $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: First calculate the total number who read $A$: that’s $30+20=50$. Then calculate the total number who read $B$; I’ll leave that to you. Finally form a fraction: if $a$ and $b$ are two numbers, the ratio of $a$ to $b$ is $\frac{a}b$.

Comment: We have $30$+$20$ = $50$  then $B$ = $20$  then $50/20$ = $5:2$ which wrong answer .

Comment: @SSK: The number who read $B$ is not $20$. It clearly has to be at least $30$, since we know that $30$ read both. So what is it?

Comment: It must be $B$ = $10$

Comment: @SSK: How can that possibly be the case? We know that it is **at least** $30$, because $30$ read both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Can you please solve this question completely with full description so i can solve further similar questions

Comment: @SSK: I’d prefer not to: it really is a very simple question. I may end up doing so, but first let me ask: do you understand how I got $30+20$ for the number who read $A$? Because if you do, you need only repeat exactly the same reasoning to get the number who read $B$.

Comment: I am sorry , i am confused !

Comment: @SSK: Okay; hang on a couple of minutes while I finish typing another answer, and I’ll expand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9257/discussion-between-ssk-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: Okay , i have found the answer You found A value user $30 + 20 = 50 $A readers . Similarly $30+5 = 35$ B readers. So ratio will be $50 / 30$ = $10:7$

Comment: @SSK: Yes! That’s exactly right.